# No Provider for Array?

Tags: angular

When I compile using ng server, the code compiles but returns this error in the Chrome console:

[image: NO PROVIDER FOR ARRAY!]

this is my app.component.ts . This is where I instantiate for the first time the MySideMenu Service

```
 import {SubMenu, MenuItem,  MySideMenu} from './Modules/Layout/side-menu/side-menu.component';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { Component, Renderer2, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation, HostBinding, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { trigger, state, style, animate, transition } from '@angular/animations';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  providers: [MySideMenu, MenuItem, SubMenu]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
   private toolBarState= false;

   ngOnInit() {
  }

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, public menuItems: MySideMenu) {
    const item1 = new MenuItem('TCPO', 'fa fa-android', [
      new SubMenu('Insumos', 'fa fa-book'),
      new SubMenu('CUB', 'fa fa-book'),
      new SubMenu('Budget', 'fa fa-book')
    ] );
    const item2 = new MenuItem('Market', 'fa fa-money', [
      new SubMenu('Sell', 'fa fa-bomb'),
      new SubMenu('Sign', 'fa fa-book'),
    ] );

    menuItems._items.push(item1);
    menuItems._items.push(item2);

  }

  onToolBarClick() {
    this.toolBarState = !this.toolBarState;
  }

}
```

The menuitems variable are passed into the component using this code:

```
 <appSideMenu [menuItems]='menuItems'></appSideMenu>
```

Now, the SideMenuModule, declares the SideMenuComponent which has the Services from where I think the error comes from:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation, ViewChild, ElementRef,
  Input, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { state, trigger, style, transition, animate } from '@angular/animations';

@Injectable()
export class MySideMenu {
  public _items: MenuItem[] = [];
  constructor (items: MenuItem[]) {
    this._items = items;
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class MenuItem {
  public _title: string;
  public _icon: string;
  public _subMenu: SubMenu[] = [];
  constructor(title: string, icon: string, subMenu: SubMenu[]) {
    this._title = title;
    this._icon = icon;
    this._subMenu = subMenu;
   }
}

@Injectable()
export class SubMenu {
  public _title: string;
  public _icon: string;
  constructor(title: string, icon: string) {
    this._title = title;
    this._icon = icon;
   }
}


@Component({
  selector: 'appSideMenu',
  templateUrl: './side-menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./side-menu.component.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger('menuTrigger', [
      state('open', style({ width: '100px' })),
      state('close', style({ width: '50px' })),
      transition('open<=>close', animate('300ms ease-in'))
    ])]
})
export class SideMenuComponent implements OnInit {

  state = 'close';
  activeMenuItem: number;
  @Input() stateSubSideMenu = 'invisible';
  @Input() menuItems: MySideMenu;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() { }

  SideMenuToggle(el: HTMLElement) {
    if (el.id === 'sidebar') {
      (this.state === 'open') ? this.state = 'close' : this.state = 'open';
      this.stateSubSideMenu = 'invisible';
    }else {
      (this.state === 'open') ? this.stateSubSideMenu = 'open' : this.stateSubSideMenu = 'close';
    }
  }

  onMenuItemClick(i: number) {
    this.activeMenuItem = i;
    (this.state === 'open') ? this.stateSubSideMenu = 'opened' : this.stateSubSideMenu = 'closed';
  }

  trackByFn(index, item) {
    return index;
  }

}
```

Comment: Remove `MySideMenu` from `providers` array

Comment: The program compiles using ng serve and ng serve -aot. BUT: With ng serve -aot it shows a warning saying that IT cannot resolve all parameters for SubMenu and MenuItem and that, will become an error in Angular V5.X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

Here is how I solved it.

The problem was in the constructor. I was defining an empty array without initializing it with empty values. Now, MenuItem is initialized in the constructor with `public _subMenu: SubMenu[]= []`, and not only `_subMenu: SubMenu[]`.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class SubMenu {
  /*public _title: string;
  public _icon: string;*/
  constructor(public _title: string, public _icon: string) {
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class MenuItem {
  /*public _title: string;
  public _icon: string;
  public _subMenu: SubMenu[] = [];*/
  constructor(public _title: string, public _icon: string, public _subMenu: SubMenu[]= []){
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class MySideMenu {
  public _items: MenuItem[] = [];
}
```

Now I can call my SideMenu in the constructor of my App.Component.ts

```
 constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, public menuItems: MySideMenu) {
    const item1 = new MenuItem('TCPO', 'fa fa-android', [
      new SubMenu('Inputs', 'fa fa-book'),
      new SubMenu('CUB', 'fa fa-book'),
      new SubMenu('Budget', 'fa fa-book')
    ] );
    const item2 = new MenuItem('Market', 'fa fa-money', [
      new SubMenu('Sell', 'fa fa-bomb'),
      new SubMenu('Sign', 'fa fa-book'),
    ] );

    menuItems._items.push(item1);
    menuItems._items.push(item2);

  }
```

And the MENU is automatically generated:

[image: Picture of MyDashBoard]

Answer (score 0):

Just put the array outside of the constructor of a class

```
export class Animal{    
    public animals: Animal[];
    constructor(private animal: Animal) {
        this.animals = new Array<Animal>();
        animals.push(animal);
    }        
}
```